# Simple example of Rails Testing Devise Controllers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, tdd

I want the simplest example to test the validity of attributes of devise's actions for new registrations (email, password, password confirmation), sign_in and forgot_password. The internet is full of RSpec ones but I want to go native with what Rails 4.2 gives me and there is absolutely nothing.

I am stuck to the default implementation:

```
require 'test_helper'

class RegistrationsControllerTest < ActionController::TestCase

  def setup
    @controller = RegistrationsController.new
    @request    = ActionController::TestRequest.new
    @response   = ActionController::TestResponse.new
    @request.env["devise.mapping"] = Devise.mappings[:user]
    @user = Registrations.new(username: "John", email: "myemail@email.com")
  end

end
```

I know this isn't too much but I am making my first steps in TDD, so please don't shoot !

How do I check for the validity of a user's attributes, for example a nil email or a password of 100 characters ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check with rails in-build [minitest](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/testing.html)

I have assumed you have overriding devise's registration_controller.

In tdd for controller you can write test cases for action.
Check modified code :-

```
require 'test_helper'

class RegistrationsControllerTest < ActionController::TestCase
  include Devise::TestHelpers # for including devise's actions

  def setup # this set up default settings for controller
    @controller = RegistrationsController.new
    @request    = ActionController::TestRequest.new
    @response   = ActionController::TestResponse.new
    @request.env["devise.mapping"] = Devise.mappings[:user]
    @user = Registrations.new(username: "John", email: "myemail@email.com")
  end

  setup do # this used for setting global variable used in test file 
    @user= users(:one) # users is the fixture file of test in which you can set default data for test environment.
  end

  test "should create user" do # then you test cases for controller
    sign_in users(:one)
    post :create, users:{email:'test@test.com, password:'XXXX'...}# you can pass arguments for create method. Please check it once, i am not sure about names
    assert_response :success 
  end


end
```

Rails minitest provides some [assertion](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/testing.html#rails-specific-assertions).

Comment: I haven't overriden devise controllers. That's the problem. But I won't do it If there's no important reason to do so.